# Object getting updated which is passed as a parameter to a method in c#

Tags: c#

I have a observed a strange behavior today in my application. I have one the methods as follows in my Data Access layer:

```
public async Task<Order> WriteOrder(Order orderDetails)
{
    try
    {
        Order updatedOrder = GenerateOrderID(orderDetails);
        Task insertOrder = orderCollection.InsertOneAsync(orderDetails);  // updatedOrder was supposed to be passed here.
       // inserts values into Database.        
    }
}

private Order GenerateOrderID(Order order)
{
    try
    {
        order.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        order.SubmittedOn = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");                
        return order;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {            
        throw;
    }
}
public class Order 
{

    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
     public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "submittedOn")]
    public string SubmittedOn { get; set; }

    // some other Data Memebers

}
```

**Explaination** :
`WriteOrder` method is receiving `orderDetails` as input parameter, then I'm passing this to `GeneratedOrderId` method , where Id and few other details are updated and the order object is returned. We are receiving the object in `updatedOrder` object(which we are not using anywhere). Then `orderdetails` object is passed to `InsertOneAsync` method and is inserted in database.

All this time I haven't noticed it , but I was supposed to pass `updatedOrder` as the parameter to `InsertOneAsync` method, instead of `orderDetails`.

But somehow it was working, i.e Id and `SubmittedOn` details as getting updated in the database.When I debugged and saw , `orderDetails` object is also getting updated (which according to me is not supposed to). Why and how is this happening?

Comment: because the they reference to same instance of object, and it's state is getting updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic thing to understand here is the when we pass an object of reference type to a method, the reference is passed by value. In your code there is no where a new object of `Order` has been created.

So what happens is that the state of same object is being updated wherever you are changing the values of properties. There is just single object in memory and you have different copies which point to the same reference.

Which means that in following method call:

```
private Order GenerateOrderID(Order order)
```

the `order` variable is holding the same object which is pointed by `orderDetails` at caller end. Two copies of reference but pointing to same object in memory.

A small change in your method will completely change the behaviour, if you create new object of `Order` in the private method. then you will see that the passed object does not gets updated. See:

```
private Order GenerateOrderID(Order order)
{
    try
    {
        order = new Order(); // note this line
        order.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        order.SubmittedOn = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");                
        return order;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {            
        throw;
    }
}
```

Now we have a new object out there which we set it's state. Now the `updatedOrder` and `orderDetails` both are reference to different objects and changing state of one will not result is changing the other.

**Note** that this applies to reference types in c# i.e. classes and interfaces objects, not to value types lile `int` , `long`, `struct` etc

Answer (score 0):

From learn.microsoft.com:

> A variable of a reference type does not contain its data directly; it
>   contains a reference to its data. When you pass a reference-type
>   parameter by value, it is possible to change the data belonging to the
>   referenced object, such as the value of a class member.

You are passing a reference to `orderDetails` object to `GenerateOrderID` method. So the object that you are modifying in this method is still the same object. `GenerateOrderID` execution changes the state of this object. So when you are passing `orderDetails` to `InsertOneAsync` method, the reference you are passing references changed object that you were modifying in `GenerateOrderID`.

I guess you were thinking that when you pass the `orderDetails`, you were passing a copy of the object - but it is not true. You are passing the copy of the reference. So if you would assign something to the `order` reference inside of the method, the `orderDetails` in `WriteOrder` method reference would still reference the old object. But here you are changing some fields of the object that you are pointing to.

I recommend reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters).